# How the big int represent in golang?

Tags: go

this code is right,

```
package main

import "fmt"

const (
    Big   = 1 << 100
    Small = Big >> 99
)

func needInt(x int) int { return x*10 + 1 }
func needFloat(x float64) float64 {
    return x * 0.1
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(needInt(Small))
    fmt.Println(needFloat(Small))
    fmt.Println(needFloat(Big))
}
```

But when i add

```
fmt.Println(Big)
```

I meet an error:

```
tmp/sandbox042871394/main.go:16: constant 1267650600228229401496703205376 overflows int
```

i am confused for

```
 const (
        Big   = 1 << 100
        Small = Big >> 99
    )
```

why there is no error for this two lines code.

Comment: "Numeric constants represent exact values of arbitrary precision and do not overflow." -- https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants

Answer (score 2):

Short answer : Big is **untyped integer constant**

Constant expressions are always evaluated exactly; intermediate values and the constants themselves may require precision significantly larger than supported by any predeclared type in the language. The following are legal declarations:

```
const Huge = 1 << 100         // Huge == 1267650600228229401496703205376  (untyped integer constant)
const Four int8 = Huge >> 98  // Four == 4                                (type int8)
```

reference https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions

Here in the constant you have not explicitly said it is an integer if said it would have failed

```
const (
    Big  int = 1 << 100
    Small       = Big >> 99
)
```

will show error

```
tmp/sandbox351128854/main.go:9: constant 1267650600228229401496703205376 overflows int
```

Comment: @blackmamba plese mark  it as done , if it answered the question

Answer (score 1):

Big and Small are untyped constants.

`fmt.Println` accepts `interface{}`. Constant is converted to its default type.

The default type is int.